# How can I properly set namespace bindings like with a namespace manager in MSXML with VB6?

Tags: xml, xpath, vb6, msxml

I'm having problems using Xpath in selectsinglenode and have found that I should be using xmlnamespacemanager. All well and good, but I can't find out where it is in VB6. Ideally I'd like to use late binding (as I'm not actually using VB6, but rather Lotusscript in Lotus Notes). Please could someone tell me how to get to it? Or, even how to use selectsinglenode in vb6 and have it work with namespaces: node = selectsinglenode("//xx:myname"), when I have a default namespace set in my XML. I don't want to remove the namespace declaration as it should go out with the finished XML.

I've declared the parser with no problem:

```
Set doc = createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
```

but I can't locate the xmlnamespace manager.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the namespaces to be used in an XPath query as follows (and a link [to the MSDN documentation of the same](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms756048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```vb
Set doc = createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
doc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
doc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:xx='urn:your.namespace' xmlns:yy='http://your/other/namespace'"
```

Pay close attention tot he single quotes inside the double quoted string.

In case you have to deal with namespace redefinitions, have a look at this [its-not-a-bug-its-a-feature report on MS Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288147). Bottom line: just define different namespace prefixes.

Why this is the way it is is excellently explained by [Geert Bormans on Experts-Exchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/XML/Q_27067860.html).

Comment: Thanks for that, I've now gotten around the problem (I think in the correct way), by including a reference to the (default) namespace URI in the Xpath string. I have something like:

Comment: ...something like: Set node = doc.selectSingleNode("//*[namespace-uri()='" & nsURI & "' and local-name()='ID']") ' Tag name. Where nsURI is a string holding the URI (since the default namespace has no prefix.

Comment: But. There's a new problem. Whilst I have this working in VB6 (because of early binding). In notes, I'm late binding to the MSXML3 which does not recognise this particular Xpath syntax. Arrrgh! Please could someone tell me how to bind to MSXML6? I know the DLL name but can't find the type library name (something like Microsoft.XMLDOM6.0?)